# Help identifying blurry kanji

Tags: meaning, kanji, reading-comprehension, writing-identification

I am currently trying to learning Japanese by reading manga. So far so good, but this kanji is too blurry for me to figure out. Anyone know what this could be?
[image]

I'm 98% sure the first character means 'eye' but the second one below it...Beats me.
Thx in advance!

Comment: [Character recognition/identification questions are considered off-topic](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 4):

That should be 「目輝」.

「目輝{めかがや}く」, for instance, means "someone's eyes are shining/beaming/sparkling, etc."

Comment: ありがとう! It was bugging me way too much.